# Problem loading JSON with comma into Snowflake

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am having an issue loading some JSON data.

The data looks like this:

```
{"geometry":{"coordinates":[12.5263,55.7664],"type":"Point"},"properties":{"created":"2021-01-19T17:08:14.114216Z","observed":"2020-01-01T23:50:00Z","parameterId":"pressure_at_sea","stationId":"06181","value":1025.1},"type":"Feature","id":"00e3bc2b-9a55-03dc-3740-005fd752f840"}
{"geometry":{"coordinates":[10.6217,55.8315],"type":"Point"},"properties":{"created":"2021-01-19T23:26:37.906088Z","observed":"2020-01-01T23:50:00Z","parameterId":"radia_glob","stationId":"06132","value":1},"type":"Feature","id":"00f7c039-6096-e2c2-5063-594c1c3bc16e"}
{"geometry":{"coordinates":[-37.6367,65.6111],"type":"Point"},"properties":{"created":"2021-01-19T23:26:37.913180Z","observed":"2020-01-01T23:50:00Z","parameterId":"radia_glob","stationId":"04360","value":0},"type":"Feature","id":"0142e2d1-9c28-e884-8d88-4b8fac5cae5d"}
```

The challenge seems to be, when I try to look at the JSON data like;

```
select $1, metadata$filename from @my_bucket/2020/2020-01.json.gz limit 3;
```

It only returns a part of the JSON:

```
$1  METADATA$FILENAME
{"geometry":{"coordinates":[12.5263     2020/2020-01.json.gz
{"geometry":{"coordinates":[10.6217     2020/2020-01.json.gz
{"geometry":{"coordinates":[-37.6367    2020/2020-01.json.gz
```

Seems like everything after the comma in the coordinates gets truncated, but I cannot figure out how to avoid that.

Br.

Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$1` is column one, which helps show that your data is being treated as CSV. Which is the default file format.

try adding [file format](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-stage.html#query-syntax-and-parameters) `FILE_FORMAT => 'my_json_file'` which would be created via:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT my_json_file TYPE = JSON;
```

Comment: That was a embarasing mistake from my side, that the file_format had slipped,
It was late last night, but still no excuse:
`select $1, metadata$filename from @dmi_bucket/2020/2020-01.json.gz (file_format => json) limit 3;`
Worked like a charm